# Spring Boot with in memory database fails

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, h2

I'm trying to test my Spring Boot application with an embedded database h2. As for dev and prod, I will be using a MySQL database.

I would like to have different application.yml and schema.sql file for each mode.

The project structure is:

```
src
--main
----resources
------application.yml
------schema.sql
--test
----resources
------application-test.yml
------schema-test.sql
```

This is my RespositoryTest :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
public class IUserRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void Should_ReturnEmployee_ForExistingEmail() {
    User oneUser=new User("john","doe","example@email.com");
    entityManager.persist(oneUser);
    List<User> userList=userRepository.findUserByEmail("example@email.com");

    assertThat(userList).isNotEmpty();
    assertThat(userList.get(0)).isNotNull();
    assertThat(userList.get(0).getEmail()).isEqualTo("example@email.com");

}
```

This is my test/resources/application-test.yml:

```
spring: 
  profiles: test
  datasource:
   url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
   platform: h2
   username: sa
   password:
   driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default-schema: mydb
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

This is my test/resources/schema-test.sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYDB
```

As for my main/resources/application.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG


spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    username: root
    password: toor
  database:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I run my app as a spring boot one, the main application.yml is used and all is good, but when I run my tests, I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "MYDB" not found; SQL statement
```

Which causes all my tests to fail.

When I try to use this project structure:

```
src
--main
----resources
------application.yml
------schema.sql
--test
----resources
------application.yml
------schema.sql
```

The test succed but when I run my app as a spring boot, the test/resources/application.yml is the one being used instead of the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests are running with the "default" profile so it will only load the "default" configurations with no suffix (i.e. -test).

Try adding @ActiveProfiles("test") to your test class to enable the test profile.

Comment: Still no luck, same error; should I put application-test in main/resources ?

Comment: Apologies I think I misunderstood your question at first.

Try using schema-h2.sql and schema-mysql.sql for your test / main schema files respectively.

Comment: It seems to be working, thank you! the working combination is: schema-h2.sql +application-test.yml + @ActiveProfiles("test") in my tests.