# DataJpaTest does not create schema

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a moderate size project using Spring Boot, and I am trying to create my first `DataJpaTest` with embedded H2, but I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table project.project.driver if exists" via JDBC Statemen
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "PROJECT" not found; SQL statement:
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037855/spring-boot-datajpatest-h2-embedded-database-create-schema) and [using a schema.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438517/why-spring-boot-2-0-application-does-not-run-schema-sql), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659722/spring-boot-with-in-memory-database-fails) and [using a test.properties in test/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037855/spring-boot-datajpatest-h2-embedded-database-create-schema), and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896935/spring-hibernate-h2-database-schema-not-found/20899790). But nothing worked. I am really baffled; this is the first time I face an issue in Spring Boot that I am not able to figure it out.

My entity classes are defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "project", catalog = "project")
@Lombok.Data
public class TableNameEntity { }
```

Any suggestion of how to force Hibernate to create the schema in H2?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a sql script which create schema in h2`s url:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:somedb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create_schema.sql'
```

And in create_schema.sql would be something like this

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS project;
```

Comment: I already try using a schema.sql script as I mentioned on my question. The script got executed, but when I try to use a repository it threw the exception saying that there is not schema named like that.